# Nohup appending output and error instead of overwrite

Tags: java, bash, logging, nohup

I am using nohup to append the java output and error to the same log file. The problem is it writes an output and then it overwrites the log file for error and output is erased.

The nohup command is

```
nohup java Daemon 1000 >logs/wrapper.log 2>logs/wrapper.log &
```

This is the message I want to log in wrapper.log from the Daemon.java

```
System.out.println("This is output that should go to the file");

System.err.println("This is error that should go to the file");
```

But only the last message is written in the file. The most reasonable answer is to know how to append the wrapper.log for outputs and errors and not the overwrite

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most portable (and my preferred method) is:

```
cmd >>logs/wrapper.log 2>&1 &
```

the `>>FD` redirect opens with the O_APPEND flag. cello's answer is a bashism (and most kshes and zsh) to redirect both stdout and stderr at once, but doesn't solve the problem of opening in append mode.

See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#somecmd_2.3E.261_.3Elogfile and associated links.

**EDIT**: I see this doesn't actually address the append problem. I'll edit the page. The links are still relevant.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. It seems to work but now the log also contains nohup:ignoring output which is polluting the logs everytime it appends  the answer. Also is  there a way I can put all the console output/error/exception in windows to a logfile when running a java program. I know we can do it with printstream in java but is there a windows console feature which does logging like the command u just showed

Comment: Normally if nohup's output is a terminal it creates a nohup.out file to save output, but that isn't the case here. If the sole purpose of the Java program's output is logging then it would probably be better to have Java open the log file itself in the necessary mode to append then to wrap with a bash script to do redirections. Unfortunately I know very little about how I/O works under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

most likely, the error-out overwrites the standard-out, as you both write to the same file.
try something like:
`nohup java Daemon 1000 &> logs/wrapper.log &`

`&>` works on some shells (bash in any case, not sure about tcsh/zsh/...), so try it out or let us know which shell you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that in a short while. I also wanted to know if there is way I can put all the console output/error/exception in windows to a logfile when running a java program. I know we can do it with  printstream in java but is there a windows console feature which does logging like nohup does.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930 gives several examples on how to do log-redirects on windows